# Override Header Title React Navigation V5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have created a nested tab navigator in my stack navigator as follows:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNav () {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}></Tab.Screen>
      <Tab.Screen name="Category" component={CategoryScreen}></Tab.Screen>
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen}></Tab.Screen>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
} 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Tab" component={TabNav}></Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="Category" component={CategoryScreen}>
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SpecialBeerScreen" component= {SpecialBeerScreen}>
          </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

However, the header now looks like Tab for each of the screens. How do I override this Header for each of the screens with a custom text, such as Home, Category etc.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you wanted to change the stack title when the tab is changed. In this case, you may use React Context to control it.

(I also put this code in snack https://snack.expo.io/@gie3d/change-header-from-tab)

edit: 1, I separated it into 3 files and assume that it's all in the same directory.

**HomeTitleContext.js**

```js
export const HomeTitleContext = React.createContext({
    title: 'default title',
    setTitle: () => {},
});
```

**App.js**

```js
import { HomeTitleContext } from './HomeTitleContext';

export default function App() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('default title');
    return (
        <HomeTitleContext.Provider
            value={{
                title,
                setTitle,
            }}
        >
            <HomeTitleContext.Consumer>
                {(ctx) => (
                    <NavigationContainer>
                        <Stack.Navigator>
                            <Stack.Screen
                                name="Tab"
                                component={TabNav}
                                options={{ title: ctx.title }} // The title will be dynamically changed here
                            />
                            <Stack.Screen
                                name="Category"
                                component={OtherScreen}
                            ></Stack.Screen>
                            <Stack.Screen
                                name="SpecialBeerScreen"
                                component={OtherScreen}
                            ></Stack.Screen>
                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </NavigationContainer>
                )}
            </HomeTitleContext.Consumer>
        </HomeTitleContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

In your component, for example: HomeScreen, you set up a useFocusEffect and change the title from setTitle which you'll get from the context

HomeScreen.js

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import { HomeTitleContext } from './HomeTitleContext';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { setTitle } = useContext(HomeTitleContext);
    useFocusEffect(() => {
        setTitle('this is home');
    });

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I tried implementing your solution, however, I get the undefined is not an object (evaluating _useContext.setTitle error. I did the same as you did, only difference is that my Homescreen is in a different file and it is a function. Any idea?

Comment: I guess you see that error because react cannot reference to HomeTitleContext. You may split that into 3 files (I updated the code in my comment above)

Comment: That worked! Why cant the HomeScreen.js not reference to the Context const in App.js but it can in Context.js?

Comment: In my first example (in a single file) the context and the HomeScreen were declared under the same scope but since your HomeScreen was in a different file, so it's in the different scope. To fix that you have to put the context in some other file and import it when you want to use.

Answer (score 8):

*Update*: This is still valid in **`react-navigation` v6**

---

Use `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute` as outlined in the react-navigation docs in the section [Setting parent screen options based on child navigator's state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state) to access information of screens in nested navigators.

Change this line

```
<Stack.Screen name="Tab" component={TabNav}></Stack.Screen>
```

to the following (adding the `options` prop):

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Tab"
  component={TabNav}
  options={({ route }) => {
    const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Home';

    switch (routeName) {
      case 'Category': {
        return {
          headerTitle: 'Category',
        };
      }
      case 'Settings': {
        return {
          headerTitle: 'Settings',
        };
      }
      case 'Home':
      default: {
        return {
          headerTitle: 'Home',
        };
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

You also have to import `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute`, so also add:

```
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No extra context. Works perfectly.